# For Sql Server Management Studio, in the year 2019, how to report a bug to Microsoft?

Tags: ssms

I ran into a fatal bug in the latest (18.1) release of Sql Server Management Studio, or SSMS.

I went to report the bug to Microsoft, but various means to do so in the past have been shut down. There seems to be no good place to report bugs to anymore.

The only option I found was a paid support subscription, which, if I'm just a conscientious, I'm not about to PAY Microsoft for QA'ing their product for them.

Answer (score 2):

> I went to report the bug to Microsoft, but various means to do so in the past have been shut down.

Microsoft migrated their feedback system a while ago to a new system. [SQL Server](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/) should be the correct community. You need an account to report the bug but it doesn't cost anything to submit something at the SQL Server feedback community.

> The only option I found was a paid support subscription

Microsoft has never charged users to report bugs. The only instance of having to pay to received updates on software is if that software is unsupported or at it's End of Life (EOL).